# Fortran - large arrays and invalid $LARGE usage

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I got some huge arrays in my program. I use *gfortran (tmd64-1) 4.7.1* version and I try to compile a code which begin with:

```
      $LARGE
       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

but I get an above error. I use `-fdollar-ok` option but as far as I know, it doesn't affect first character in a symbol name. How can I pass by the problem?

Comment: Is `$LARGE` supposed to be a directive to the compiler?  Then try removing it.   Or is it an array name?   Then rename it.

Comment: This looks to be a [Microsoft compiler directive](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/77561) from back in the day. I'd follow @M.S.B. 's advice and just leave it out, as - as I understand the option - I don't think it would be necessary with gfortran (although with ifort you might need `-heap-arrays`).

Comment: Must be a very old program.  This is an MS directive from the 16-bit Microsoft Fortran 5.0 compiler to allow arrays to span more than 64K. Just remove it.  You don't need it on a 32/64 bit system.